# Quartic Surface with 15 ordinary double points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, singularity

Does anyone know of a quartic surface that has 15 ordinary double points and no other singularities.  For example a [Kummer Surface](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KummerSurface.html) has 16 ordinary double points, also called nodes, or $A_1$ singularities.  And the [Hessian of the Cayley Cubic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CayleyCubic.html) is also a quartic surface, but with 14 ordinary double points.  Explicitly it has the following equation.

$x_0^2(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3)+x_1^2(x_0x_2+x_0x_3+x_2x_3)+x_2^2(x_0x_1+x_0x_3+x_1x_3)+x_3^2(x_0x_1+x_0x_2+x_1x_2)=0$

So my question is can you give me the EQUATION of a quartic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ with 15 ordinary double points and no other singularities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general hyperplane section of the Igusa quartic threefold
$$
\Bigg\{ \sum_{i=1}^6 x_i = 4\Big(\sum_{i=1}^6 x_i^4\Big) - \Big(\sum_{i=1}^6 x_i^2\Big)^2 = 0 \Bigg\} \subset \mathbb{P}^5
$$
has 15 ordinary double points.

Comment: I'm looking for an equation in only 4 variables though, in $\mathbb{P}^3$.  Do you have an example of one of those?

Comment: Using the first of the above equations you can exclude one variable. Using a hyperplane equation, you can exclude another, and then you end up with 4 variables only.

Comment: I deleted $x_6$ and then made the substitution $x_5 \rightarrow -x_1-x_2-x_3-x_4$ which works.  Thank you!